# Mould like on one window only

Tags: outdoor, brick, mold

I have a weird mould issue. The only window in the house/street like it. There is no leaking pipe etc.

[image]

Comment: Whihc part is the mold

Comment: Why have you concluded that is mould and not something like soot?

Answer (score 1):

The brick looks dark / wet to me. I suspect the guttering / soffits above are leaking. I'd get up on a ladder and inspect the roof for cracked slates / tiles, and penetrations. You might be able to do this from the ground with a pair of binoculars, but do it when your neighbours are out!

On a nice dry day, if you tip water on it you might be able to see which bit of the wall gets wet first. Obviously water + height + ladders might not be the best combo so take care.